# Meteor: Async Callback issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, stripe-payments

Currently I have the user click submit and then a click event occurs where a token is created and a method is called. What I am trying to do is after the charge get a callback which says if it is successfully or not. If successful it will run router.go to the confirmation page. If it is not successful then it will let the user know the card has been declined. All the above I can code out except despite non stop tinkering, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the message back to the event.

Here is my server side method:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    'chargeCard': function(token,amount,email) {
      var Stripe = StripeAPI('where the key info guys');
      // get a sync version of our API async func
      var stripeCustomersCreateSync=Meteor.wrapAsync(Stripe.customers.create,Stripe.customers);
      // call the sync version of our API func with the parameters from the method call
      var result=stripeCustomersCreateSync({
        description: 'Woot! A new customer!',
        card: token,
        email: email
      }, function(error,result) {
        if(error) {
          return error;
        }
        return 'Success';
      });
      return result;
    }
});
```

and my Client side method:

```
    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('#cc-number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: expM,
      exp_year: expY,
      name: $('#fn').val(),
      address_zip: $('#postCode').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
  }
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    var $form = $('form');

    if (response.error) {
      // Show the errors on the form
      $form.find('.validation').text(response.error.message);
      return false;
    } else {
      var token = response.id;
      var amount = 15000;
      var Payid = $('#pid').text();
      var userEmail = Leaguemembers.findOne({_id: Payid}).Email;
      Meteor.call('chargeCard', token, amount,userEmail, function (error, result) {
        console.log(error,result); alert(result); alert(error);
        }
      );
    }
  };
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I went back into the backend and I can see the errors being generated through console.log but still am unable to pass it back to where the call was made to display those errors to the user or pass them to the confirmation page. All I seem to get is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meteor.call should look like this

```
Meteor.call('chargeCard',token,amount,username,function(err,result){
    if(!err){
       Router.go("theRoute") //if there is not error go to the route
     }else{
       console.log(err.reason) // show the error
    }
  })
```

Comment: I did your change but the issue is that its not passing the error. I fiddled with it a bit and finally got it to return but it returns this weird message: Object {_bitField: 1, _promise0: Object}

Comment: both...I managed to now receive the success message by removing the function(error,charge). Working backwards with the function to pull the error.

Comment: Well as of now I am seeing if a success message came in. If not then I assume its an error. Its not the best way of doing it but it should be fine I think. Than you for your help with this.